# MySql - how to delete records based on a word?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no experience in database administration and I find myself in a situation where I have to bury it. I have a database in which I have several thousand records in the name of which is the word "Year_2014". I want to remove them
I tried to use the command but removes everything:

```
SELECT * FROM nkigz_flippingbook_pages WHERE checked_out = 'Year_2014';
DELETE FROM nkigz_flippingbook_pages WHERE checked_out LIKE 'Year_2014';
```

Can you tell me how can I deal with this problem?

Regards
Igor

Comment: It should remove everything that matched the condition on `checked_out`.  What else is being removed?

Comment: Also why use `LIKE` operator if `=` does same thing in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM nkigz_flippingbook_pages WHERE checked_out LIKE '%Year_2014%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use % in LIKE.
Example:

> SELECT * FROM nkigz_flippingbook_pages WHERE checked_out = '%Year_2014%';

Returns everything that has the expression: 'Year_2014'

Comment: I do not know if this is the case, but in the search results I find the phrase to be retained: "Year_2017"

Answer (score 1):

This command will delete whole row if it found "Year_2014"

```
DELETE FROM nkigz_flippingbook_pages WHERE checked_out like '%Year_2014%';
```

If you want to replace this word with blank space, you can use below command (this will not delete your row)

```
Update nkigz_flippingbook_pages set checked_out = ' ' WHERE checked_out ='Year_2014';
```

Hope this helps!